# I need to refer to an image that can be pointed regardless of the URL of the Controller in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm doing an exercise in Spring MVC and I have to show the images of the Italian and English flag in every part of the website.

I have a footer that is called by every page

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<div>
    <p>All rights reserved</p>
</div>

<h3>
    <spring:message code="addUsers.form.changeLanguage.label" />
</h3>
<section class="locale-link">
    <a href="?language=en"> <img src="static/images/US.png" /></a> 
    <a href="?language=it"><img src="static/images/IT.png" /></a>
</section>
```

This is the position where I've put the images:  [position of the images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15P7L.png)

Unfortunately I can see the correct visualization of the images of the footer footer only in the home page:[correct visualization of the images in the home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P63gt.png)

On the other hand, I lose the reference to the image if I am in another folder: [wrong visualization of the images in a not-home folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r92tH.png)

How can I fix this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Your `src` of the `img` tag is relative **not** absolute. Prefix with a `/` to make it absolute. I.e. from the root.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/images/IT.png">
```